# Core Data to create TableViewCells Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data, swift

So I am trying to create a TableViewCell with Core Data, but when defining the cells, they all turn in the last input at the Core Data. The app is taking the user textfield input and turning into the table view cell label, and the zipInStr to the TableViewCell detail.

This is the function that add the values to the CoreData:

```
 @IBAction func createFav(sender: AnyObject) {
       //Defining variables to save at core data
        var newTextInput = textInput.text
        var trimmNewTextInput = newTextInput.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
        var zipInStr: String = zipCode.text!


            var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
            var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

            var newFav = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Cells", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

            newFav.setValue(zipInStr, forKey: "favsDictKey")
            newFav.setValue(trimmNewTextInput, forKey: "favsDictValues")

            context.save(nil)

            println(newFav)

        textInput.text = String()

        }
    }
```

And this is the function that is creating the TableViewCells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cells")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    println(results)
    if (results.count == 0){
       println("Error")

    } else {

        for res in results{

            cell.textLabel?.text = res.valueForKey("favsDictValues") as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = res.valueForKey("favsDictKey") as? String
        }
    }
     return cell
}
```

I am pretty sure the error have something to do with the loop, since when I print the `results` I can see all the inputs with its respective values

Comment: You should execute that fetch request, and populate `results`, only once, perhaps in `viewDidLoad`.  Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use `indexPath.row` as an index to access the relevant item from the `results` array.  Alternatively take a look at NSFetchResultsController which (with some boilerplate code) makes mapping CoreData to a tableView pretty straight forward.

Comment: Can you show me how to do the first way you said? I am really new to Core Data and I am really lost

Comment: Use an NSFetchedResultsController: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question... By "the error" do you mean that fact that this line is printing -- "println("Error")"? Or are you actually getting an error?

Comment: This error line is not giving me a error is just for me to know that there is no cells specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, to get your current setup working, make `results` into a stored property.  Add

```
var results : NSArray = NSArray()
```

at the beginning of your class definition.  Then move the code to populate the array from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to `viewDidLoad`:

```
var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Cells")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
println("\(results)")
```

Now, the tableView will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` multiple times, once for each row that it wants to display.  So the code in that method needs to configure it with the data for the relevant row.  The `indexPath` provided as an argument to the call indicates which row (and section, if you break your table view into sections) the tableView is requesting.  So your code does not need to loop through all the values in `results` - it just needs to reference the correct element of the array.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let res = results[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject
    cell.textLabel?.text = res.valueForKey("favsDictValues") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = res.valueForKey("favsDictKey") as? String
    return cell
}
```

That should get your tableView working (unless I've messed up some optionals or casts -  if so, sorry, I'm still getting up to speed with Swift).

This approach will work fine provided your data is relatively static (i.e. doesn't change whilst the tableView is being displayed) and provided you don't want to break the table into sections.  In either of these situations (and, some would say, in any case), you should use an NSFetchedResultsController.  That will automatically keep track of how many (and which) items appear in each section, etc, and can also be configured to automatically update the tableView if new items are added to the data whilst it is being displayed.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking some tutorials at the youtube and I found one that showed this approach. Now I am starting to understand Core Data a little bit more!

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is not correct. You should employ a `NSFetchedResultsController` (see Xcode template for easy code to copy) - this is the best way to populate a table view with Core Data.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you simply retrieve the correct item for the index path. Don't put fetch request into this method, as it is potentially called many times (e.g. while scrolling).

```
let cell = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Cells
```

*BTW, "Cells" seems to be an inappropriate name for an entity. You need a singular that describes the data you are displaying. Perhaps, "Favorite"?*